# How to monitor performance of Lumen "PHP Micro-Framework By Laravel"?

Tags: php, laravel, performance, monitoring, lumen

According to https://github.com/laravel/telescope/issues/112 Telescope isn't adapted for lumen yet, yet i realy need a simple way to monitor my DB queries and code performance in Lumen, is there an existing package to do so?